# Mailchimp api: retrieving poll results

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

Is there a way to get the members to a certain response of poll without the need to create segments?

I am sending mails and have a poll included (basically participating at an event).
Now I would like to easily collect the respondents for an event from various mails (announcement, invitation, reminder 1, reminder 2,..)

Currently I need to create segments for each response where I need to reference the campaigns individually. So whenever I send a campaign (email) I need to update all segments as there need to be a segment per question, which I would like to avaoid.

Hope thats clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar question and after a review of the mailchimp API docs, in particular the [reports section](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/) I realized there was not a way to retrieve poll results.

After my review, I followed-up with mailchimp and they mentioned access to poll results via API is not available - detailed comments with image attached below:

**MailChimp Response - Start** 
"To be completely honest and transparent, there currently wouldn't be a way of accessing the campaign poll result data directly through the report... With that being said, it would be possible to use the API to create segments based on poll response, then call those segments to view the number of responses for each option, as well as the specific subscribers who chose each individual option.

More info here: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/segments/

**MailChimp Response - End**

As you can see, although accessing poll results via the API is not available, there is a work around using a method.

Good luck!

[image: complete mailchimp response]